# overlapping feature order google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How do I programatically in javascript define which feature is on top of another when they overlap

[image]

In This picture I clicked on the smaller geographic feature, however the information for the outer geographic feature came up.  I would like to programmatically put the smaller features on top.

Here is the my code to populate the map in javascript-

```js
map.data.loadGeoJson('<path to my geojson definition>');
map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
  let color = 'gray';
  console.log(feature);
  if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  return ({
    fillColor: color,
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeWeight: 1
  });
});

map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {
  let name = event.feature.getProperty('name');

  let contentString = '<h4>Polygon Info</h4><br>';

  contentString += '<p>';
  if (name) {
    contentString += '<b>Name:</b>' + name + '<br>';
  }        
  contentString += '</p>';

  let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    position: event.latLng
  });

  infowindow.open(map);

  event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
});
```

Note I reversed the order of the features in the geojson file itself and that did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the z-index property of feature.Assuming you can disinguish one feature entry from another you can adjust z-index depending on your need in `setStyle()` function, just work out appropriate values

```
return ({
  fillColor: color,
  strokeColor: color,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  zIndex: zIndex
});
```

Or update z-index when mouse enters

```
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  map.data.overrideStyle(e.feature, {
  //strokeColor: '#1e3a2a',
  //strokeWeight: 2, /* can also change these like hover effect */
   zIndex: 6
  });
});

map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  map.data.revertStyle();
});
```